# Spaces Between Table Rows In IE7/8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I would like there to be spaces between rows of my table in IE7/8. I did this:

```
.selector tr {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

Which works in Firefox but not in IE7/8 where the 3px gap doesn't appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if this may work in some browsers, changing the `display` of a table row feels like an awful hack. Don't do it.

The only valid, cross-browser way that I know of is to give each `td` some `padding-bottom`, or maybe a transparent `border`:

```
.selector tr td { padding-bottom: 3px }
```

Comment: Yeah, the thought of changing the `display` of a `tr` gives me the heebie-jeebies.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do:

```
.selector tr td {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

If you're also using `<th>` tags then do:

```
.selector tr td, .selector tr th {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

You should not need that `display: block;` rule, but perhaps it's overriding something else you have in your stylesheets.